# Mirror a 2d array on a JFrame Board

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array, 2d-games

I am creating a board game where an n by n board (5 x 5 in this example) contains random letters in each cell. The letters are selected randomly from an array of strings and there is a 2d array of buttons to place them into the JFrame following a for loop for the 2d array of randomly selected letters (as Strings). The intent of the program below is to display a 5 by 5 board of buttons, which is not working. I would be very grateful for any help or instruction on fixing this problem.

```
package com.content;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class WordDisplay {
   static int random;
   static JFrame frame = new JFrame("WordMatch");

   public static void newFrame() {
      frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
      //frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(false);
   }

   public static void fillFrame(){


      String[] Letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g", 
                          "h","i","j","k","l","m","n",
                          "o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
                          "v","w","x","y","z"};

      JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[5][5];
      for (int r = 0;r<5;r++){
          for (int c = 0;c<5;c++){
              buttons[r][c] = new JButton("");
          }
      }
      String[][] Board = new String[5][5];
      for (int r = 0;r<5;r++){

         for (int c = 0;c<5;c++){

            random  = (int)(Math.random() * 25);
            Board[r][c] = Letters[random];
            buttons[r][c].setText(Board[r][c]);

            System.out.print(Board[r][c]);

            frame.add(buttons[r][c]);

          }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){

      newFrame();
      fillFrame();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

(Sorry for any code formatting issues)

Comment: What specifically isn't working? The displaying of the letters? Can you be a bit more specific as to what it is you're trying to do and what is currently happening?

Comment: Only the last button is showing, instead of all 25.

Comment: Can't you just uncomment out the frame.setLayout() line?

Comment: Based on your example code, the `JFrame` is defaulting to a `BorderLayout`, which will only show the last component which was added the particular position (in this case `CENTER`)

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it, I needed to add the grid layout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when you have a 2D array and you want to mirror it, what you should do is basically this:

```
for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<array[x].length;y++){
        array[x][y]=array[(array[x].length)-x][y]
    }
}
```

If you could be more specific with the problem of your code, I should be able to be more helpfull...